# img and button placing bootstrap inside a colum div row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem using bootstrap, I want to make that the blue buttons stay nicely underneath that picture.

the no img link: [img](https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/image-preview-icon-picture-placeholder-for-website-or-uiux-design-vector-id1222357475?k=20&m=1222357475&s=612x612&w=0&h=jPhUdbj_7nWHUp0dsKRf4DMGaHiC16kg_FSjRRGoZEI=)

This is how it looks like:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <input id="InputFile1" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output1', 'spanIMG1')" hidden>
    <img id="output1" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="../Images/noIMG.jpg">
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">First Image</a>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <input id="InputFile2" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output2', 'spanIMG2')" hidden>
    <img id="output2" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="../Images/noIMG.jpg">
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">Second Image</a>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <input id="InputFile3" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output3', 'spanIMG3')" hidden>
    <img id="output3" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="../Images/noIMG.jpg">
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">Third Image</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, add class `d-flex flex-column` to each `.col` and then add `mx-auto` class to each child in that column

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
    <input class="mx-auto" id="InputFile1" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output1', 'spanIMG1')" hidden>
    <img class="mx-auto rounded" id="output1" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/image-preview-icon-picture-placeholder-for-website-or-uiux-design-vector-id1222357475?k=20&m=1222357475&s=612x612&w=0&h=jPhUdbj_7nWHUp0dsKRf4DMGaHiC16kg_FSjRRGoZEI=">
    <a class="btn btn-info mx-auto mt-1" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">First Image</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
    <input class="mx-auto" id="InputFile2" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output2', 'spanIMG2')" hidden>
    <img class="mx-auto rounded" id="output2" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/image-preview-icon-picture-placeholder-for-website-or-uiux-design-vector-id1222357475?k=20&m=1222357475&s=612x612&w=0&h=jPhUdbj_7nWHUp0dsKRf4DMGaHiC16kg_FSjRRGoZEI=">
    <a class="btn btn-info mx-auto mt-1" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">Second Image</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
    <input class="mx-auto" id="InputFile3" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output3', 'spanIMG3')" hidden>
    <img class="mx-auto rounded" id="output3" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/image-preview-icon-picture-placeholder-for-website-or-uiux-design-vector-id1222357475?k=20&m=1222357475&s=612x612&w=0&h=jPhUdbj_7nWHUp0dsKRf4DMGaHiC16kg_FSjRRGoZEI=">
    <a class="btn btn-info mx-auto mt-1" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">Third Image</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice guide for the grid system in bootstrap: https://hub.packtpub.com/bootstrap-grid-system-responsive-website/

You need to make two rows - first row with the pictures, and the second row with the links:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <input id="InputFile1" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output1', 'spanIMG1')" hidden>
    <img id="output1" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="../Images/noIMG.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <input id="InputFile2" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output2', 'spanIMG2')" hidden>
    <img id="output2" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="../Images/noIMG.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <input id="InputFile3" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event, 'output3', 'spanIMG3')" hidden>
    <img id="output3" style="height: 135px; width: 135px;" src="../Images/noIMG.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">First Image</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">Second Image</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <a class="btn btn-info" style="width: 135px;" href="javascript:{}">Third Image</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its it possible to make  it stay in the midle like this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/FmzxRUe)

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. You could use `offset` to move them around a bit.